# Notepad++ convert leading spaces to tabs upon entry

Tags: coding-style, notepad++, indentation

Very close to reverse of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455037/notepad-convert-tabs-to-spaces) question. I prefer coding with 2-whitespace indentation, but need to have files indented with tabs to align with project convention. What I would like to do is *preferably automatically* convert 2 spaces upon entry to tab symbol in Notepad++ and have the editor configured to tab length of 2.

A possible manual way for doing this could be `Edit->Blank Operations->Space to TAB` but this converts *all* of my spaces to tabs, even those of length 1 - which are, for example, spaces between function arguments, not just leading spaces.

In a perfect case scenario I'm trying to achieve formatting style as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208065/how-to-get-indent-with-tabs-align-with-spaces-behavior-in-xcode), but with typing just spaces and the editor taking care of the rest.
I'm on Notepad++ 6.0, but willing to upgrade if this helps

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me complete the answer of Ari Okkonen to add a workaround to the problem commented by Sergii Zaskaleta of mixed tabs and spaces at the beginning of the line.

1. Settings->Preferences->Tab Settings->Tab size: 2 (if not already)
2. Edit->Blank Operations->Space to TAB **(Leading)**
3. Select a block of lines of text with the problem of mixed spaces and tabs. Press [Tab] and [Shift]+[Tab] to add and remove a tab from each line. In the process, the leading spaces had been converted to tabs.

Answer (score 5):

A manual way that seems to work: After having edited the file before saving you may try (Works in Notepad++ v6.8.3):

1. Settings->Preferences->Tab Settings->Tab size: **2** *(if not already)*
2. Edit->Blank Operations->Space to TAB **(Leading)**

Comment: I've checked and its good. Sadly, there's a somewhat of a limitation: leading [Tab][Tab][Space][Space] does not get converted to [Tab][Tab][Tab], whereas [Space][Space][Tab] becomes [Tab][Tab] and [Space][Space][Tab][Space][Space] become [Tab][Tab][Tab]. Anyways, an improvement already, thank you!