# How do I generate a Swift *Runtime* warning message?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I would like to add a warning that shows up like the "Main Thread Checker" in the Issue Navigator under the *Runtime* tab.

I have used assert() in the past but I don't want to cause a crash, just note the issues in the navigator.

I want the error to only show if the code is *run* and not at compile time.

Maybe the answer is that one doesn't exist?

Comment: This looks promising, if you haven't seen it already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46372548/how-to-log-a-warning-that-shows-up-as-a-runtime-issue-in-xcode

Comment: Thanks, looks like a similar question

Answer (score -2):

```
#warning("My message")

#error("Some Error")
```

I use this feature frequently to mark some TODOs: #warning("TODO: Some work")

Comment: I'm looking for a *Runtime* warnings / errors, those are compile time errors

Comment: @BobbyRohweder You said you wanted the message to show in the Issues Navigator which is where compiler warning/error messages are displayed.  Perhaps you could specify your requirements more accurately.

Comment: Im sorry, I was trying to be clear with `under the Runtime tab`, where the main thread checker reports them.